# How to implement searchbar in chrome new tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the `chrome_url_overrides` in a chrome extension to create a custom new tab.
I want to implement a search bar to let the user doing research using duckduckgo. I'm not sure on how to configure the form to doing research, I don't want to use an api service to achive this, how I need to configure the options to create an experience like the original new tab one?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @wOxxOm for options I mean the url that the form needs to point to do a search. This is what I need to know.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand the point,I don't need autocomplete and I don't want to emulate at all the default new tab. I need only to redirect the user to the result page and I need to know what's is the url that needs to be set into the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Ah, if I understand you correctly, `<form action="https://duckduckgo.com/">` and then your input should have `name="q"`

Comment: yes. I've found the duckduck go endpoint for autocomplete, now I need to make things working in vue. Thank you for the help.